# How can admins see which G Suite package is used for their account?

Tags: g-suite-administrator

Where in G Suite's dashboard can admins see [which package](https://gsuite.google.com/intl/en/pricing.html) is used for their G Suite account?

[image]

Comment: In the invoice and in the admin panel. If you need further help please add a brief-description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Added a screenshot of the admin panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Billing is the only way to see it:

[image]